# Resolution changing between mosaic dataset and output from mosaic to new raster tool viewed in ArcScene?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, 3d-analyst, arcscene, mosaic, resolution

ArcScene cannot accept the mosaic dataset (`Raster 1`) so I used the Mosaic to New Raster tool to create a raster (`Raster 2`) that we can use in ArcScene.

The problem which I face is the resolution in ArcScene is changed for `Raster 2`
but in ArcMap it's same as `Raster 1`.

[image: mosaic dataset tool]

[image: mosaic to new raster tool]

Comment: Can anybody help